# How can I build a Sorcerer who focuses on debuffing and debilitating effects?

Tags: dnd-4e, new-players, sorcerer

A friend of mine is about to start his own 4e campaign, and I'll be playing a Sorcerer. We're starting from scratch at level 1. I need your advice on how to build him the way I want him, though:

I want my Sorcerer to focus on debuffing enemies or placing debilitating conditions. He should do stuff like lowering their defences, knocking them prone, or making them dazed or immobilised. I don't mind not being able to deal high amounts of damage.

I would *strongly prefer* to play a Human, Tiefling or Half-Elf, and to use the Arcane Wellspring Paragon Path.

How can I build this Sorcerer? What race, powers and so on should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Does it need to *mechanically* be a Sorcerer?**

Sorcerers are strikers; they're not intended to debuff, they're intended to deal damage (and they're not even amazing at *that*). Sorcerers don't have very many debuffing powers, and the ones they *do* have aren't especially good.

You've sort of asked, "Can I make a fighter who only casts spells on people?" Yes, you *can*, but they won't be very good; why not just make a spellcaster and *describe* them as being a fighter? In short, you should generally pick your class to reflect the *mechanics* you want your character to have, not the *fluff* you want them to have.

Would you be willing to make a character who is *mechanically* a wizard or warlock and just *describe* them as a sorcerer? Warlocks are also (technically) strikers but lean much more heavily toward control than other strikers, especially certain builds, and wizards are excellent controllers. Note that humans & tieflings make very good wizards, and all three of your preferred races make great warlocks.

<sup>*(If this approach interests you, leave me a comment and I'll put together a basic build for you when I get a chance.)*</sup>

Comment: Great answer, so many people focus on the fluff when 4e's separation of fluff and crunch fully supports reskinning.